# How to create two tables in a sqlite database using two activities in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have created two tables user_table and vehicle_table in a sqlite database user_data in which i am accepting data using two .xml activities. One activity page works fine but the page i used to operate the second table isn't working. its showing: "App has stopped working". here are all the codes. Please help me find the errors here.

**Database: user_data_sql.java**

```
package com.example.login;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class user_data_sql extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME= "user_data1.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME= "user_table";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME2= "vehicle_table";
    public static final String COL_1= "USER_ID";
    public static final String COL_2= "FIRST_NAME";
    public static final String COL_3= "LAST_NAME";
    public static final String COL_4= "PHN_NO";
    public static final String COL_5= "DOB";
    public static final String COL_6= "ADHAR_NO";
    public static final String COL_7= "LICENSE_NO";
    public static final String COL_8= "LICENSE_VALIDITY";
    public static final String COLV_1 = "VehicleID";
    public static final String COLV_3 = "RCNumber";
    public static final String COLV_4 = "RCValidity";
    public static final String COLV_5 = "ChassisNumber";
    public static final String COLV_6 = "InsuranceNumber";
    public static final String COLV_7 = "InsuranceValidity";
    public static final String COLV_8 = "PUCValidity";

    public user_data_sql(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME+"(USER_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FIRST_NAME TEXT, " +
                "LAST_NAME TEXT, PHN_NO INT, DOB TEXT, ADHAR_NO INT, LICENSE_NO TEXT, LICENSE_VALIDITY INT)");
        //recentchanges
        db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME2+"(VehicleID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "RCNUMBER TEXT,RCValidity Date,ChassisNumber TEXT,InsuranceNumber INTEGER,InsuranceValidity Date," +
                "PUCValidity Date,USER_ID INT, FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES user_table(USER_ID))");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME2);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String FIRST_NAME,String LAST_NAME, String PHN_NO, String DOB, String ADHAR_NO,
                              String LICENSE_NO, String LICENSE_VALIDITY)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, FIRST_NAME);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, LAST_NAME);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, PHN_NO);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, DOB);
        contentValues.put(COL_6, ADHAR_NO);
        contentValues.put(COL_7, LICENSE_NO);
        contentValues.put(COL_8, LICENSE_VALIDITY);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return result != -1;
    }
    public boolean insertData1(String rcNumber,String rcValidity,String chassisNumber,
                               String insuranceNumber,String insuranceValidity,String pucValidity){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues1 = new ContentValues();
        contentValues1.put(COLV_3,rcNumber);
        contentValues1.put(COLV_4,rcValidity);
        contentValues1.put(COLV_5,chassisNumber);
        contentValues1.put(COLV_6,insuranceNumber);
        contentValues1.put(COLV_7,insuranceValidity);
        contentValues1.put(COLV_8,pucValidity);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME2,null,contentValues1);
        return result != -1;

    }
}
```

**page1: qr2.java**

```
package com.example.login;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeEncoder;

public class QR2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    user_data_sql myDb;
    EditText etFirstName,etLastName,etPhoneNumber, etDOB, etAadhar, etLicenseNumber, etLicenseValidity;
    Button Generate2, Save, Next;
    ImageView output;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_q_r2);
        myDb =new user_data_sql(this);

        etFirstName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirstName);
        etLastName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLastName);
        etPhoneNumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhoneNumber);
        etDOB=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDOB);
        etAadhar=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAadhar);
        etLicenseNumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLicenseNumber);
        etLicenseValidity=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLicenseValidity);

        Generate2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGenerate2);
        output=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Output);
        Save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        Next=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        AddData();
        Generate2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //get input value from edit text
                String data = etFirstName.getText().toString().trim();
                MultiFormatWriter writer=new MultiFormatWriter();
                try {
                    BitMatrix matrix=writer.encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,350,350);
                    //Initialise barcode encoder
                    BarcodeEncoder encoder=new BarcodeEncoder();
                    //Initialise bitmap
                    Bitmap bitmap=encoder.createBitmap(matrix);
                    //set bitmap to image view
                    output.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    //initialise input manager
    InputMethodManager manager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    //hide soft keyboard
                    manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etFirstName.getApplicationWindowToken(),0);
                } catch (WriterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
        Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(QR2.this, Vehicle_info.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
            }
        });


    }
    public void AddData()
    {
        Save.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean isInserted= myDb.insertData(etFirstName.getText().toString(),
                                etLastName.getText().toString(),etPhoneNumber.getText().toString(),
                                etDOB.getText().toString(),etAadhar.getText().toString(),
                                etLicenseNumber.getText().toString(),
                                etLicenseValidity.getText().toString());
                        if(isInserted)
                            Toast.makeText(QR2.this,"Data Inserted",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(QR2.this,"Data NOT Inserted",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

**page2: Vehicle_info.java**

```
package com.example.login;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Vehicle_info extends AppCompatActivity {
    user_data_sql myDb;
    EditText editrcNumber,editrcValidity,editchassisNumber,editinsuranceNumber,editinsuranceValidity,editpucValidity;
    Button btnAddData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vehicle_info);
        myDb = new user_data_sql(this);
        editrcNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etRCNumber);
        editrcValidity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etRCValidity);
        editchassisNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etChassisNumber);
        editinsuranceNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etInsuranceNumber);
        editinsuranceValidity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etInsuranceValidity);
        editpucValidity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPUCValidity);
        btnAddData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        AddData1();
    }

    public void AddData1()
    {
        btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean isInserted= myDb.insertData1(editrcNumber.getText().toString(),
                                editrcValidity.getText().toString(),editchassisNumber.getText().toString(),
                                editinsuranceNumber.getText().toString(),editinsuranceValidity.getText().toString(),
                                editpucValidity.getText().toString());
                        if(isInserted)
                            Toast.makeText(Vehicle_info.this,"Data Inserted",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(Vehicle_info.this,"Data NOT Inserted",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the stack-trace ***"App has stopped working"*** could have many causes.

- You should perhaps check out https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/ to finds out how to obtain a stack-trace amongst other debugging techniques.

However, a clue to very likely cause is ***"//recentchanges"***. It looks as though you may have added the second table after running the App but not properly catered for the changes to be applied to the database.

The `onCreate` method in the DatabaseHelper (i.e. your **user_data_sql** class) is only run/invoked when the database doesn't exist. As such this was probably run only with the first table.

The `onUpgrade` method where you drop and recreate the tables will only run if the database version is increased. The database version is the 4th parameter passed to the super call. You have:-

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, 1);
```

As such it appears that you have not allowed for the `onUpgrade` method to run.

**Fix 1**
Changing the super call to :-

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, 2 /*<<<<<<<<<< INCREASED DATABASE VERSION*/);
```

- comment after 4th parameter included just to highlight the change made to the Database Version number.

Should result in the onUpgrade method being called which should then drop the tables and then create them (losing any existing data) and it is quite probable that your code will then work, or at least progress further.

- Note that typically you would limit the code run in the `onUpgrade` method to only those steps needed to introduce the changes by utilising/inspecting the oldversion (2nd parameter **i** in your code) and the newversion (3rd parameter or **i1** in your code).

**Fix 2/3**
An alternative and perhaps simpler could be to delete the database in which case the Databasehelper's `onCreate` method would run, the database version number can remain as 1. The simplest way to delete the database would be to uninstall the app and then rerun the app. You could also delete the files in the data/data/<package_name>/databases folder (e.g. via Android Studio's Device Explorer) and then re run the app.

- Note as originally stated this is just a guess as to a likely cause of your problem(s).